# Photodiode OP-AMP circuit for UV light radiation

Tags: arduino, amplifier, photodiode, radiation

The project: The aim is to be able to use the photodiode to detect plasma (radiation in the UV light spectrum). The photodiode suggested for this application is the BPX65 and I currently have access to a AD622AN low instrumentation amplifier.

OP-AMP: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD622.pdf

Photodiode: http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic1/00181579_0.pdf/BPX%2065,%20Lead%20(Pb)%20Free%20Product%20-%20RoHS%20Compliant.pdf

Ideally, the project requires this to be connected to the 5V supply of an Arduino board in order to provide a signal on whether there is a presence of plasma or not. Accuracy is not key but quick responses are of importance.
Without any circuitry, when the plasma is active, the photodiode is able to detect a small voltage drop from 260mV to 240mV. Reading analogue values from the Arduino board with the a simple resistor to ground is unable to detect any change while the plasma is present, so I decided to add an instrumentation amplifier by following a basic non-inverting configuration as below:

[image]

However, this has made little or no change to the output values detect. Would anyone be kind enough to shed some light on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: that is a visible light and IR photodiode. its UV sensitivity is very low. it is most sensitive in the IR spectrum.

Comment: I believe it detects some levels of UV radiation, so could this not be used for this application? A more selective photodiode choice for the UV range very experience.

Comment: You could try a UV LED and see if that performs a bit better. Not sure about the response time though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have heard that the UV LED's are rather slow to respond but might be worth a shot. Ideally, I would like the response to be quite fast.

Comment: If anyone could suggest alternatives to the photodiode above I would be very grateful. I'm somewhat struggling to find one that is not overly expensive.

Comment: "Without any circuitry, when the plasma is active, the photodiode is able to detect a small voltage drop from 260mV to 240mV." - A photodiode is designed to detect light, not voltage. Do you mean the photodiode _output_ changes from 260mV to 240mV (?) when the plasma is active? How did you measure this? Are you sure it was detecting UV and not ambient light or EMI?

Comment: Hi Bruce, Sorry that's what I meant. The output changes from 260mV to 240mV. I simply measured this using a multimeter while keeping the photodiode placed under the plasma. This may well have been due to ambient lighting with the plasma active there was a small change in the output.

Comment: Would this be useful for my application: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/1918guva.pdf

Comment: (1) I've used the diode in the other orientation for a TIA, applying a virtual ground. (2) Laser dyes are used to downshift wavelengths into the better part of quantum sensitivity for a particular Si diode; for UV. (3) A very thin gold layer may be used on the front (exposed) side to "drive" electrons produced by shorter wavelengths nearer the surface into the depletion zone to get collected; for UV. (4) You may need fused silica or sapphire for a window/lens. Typical glass won't do it.

Comment: The diode is somewhat sensitive in the high UV region, so it should sense something. Are you sure that the plasma is emitting in the >350nm region? A photodiode is a current output device, so I would suggest looking into a transimpedance amplifier configuration.